# Whats missing in this code, and is it right?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, max, min

I have to write a code in c, where the user can type numbers above 0.
If the user types a number below or = 0, then following will be the
output: the minimum of the numbers, the maximum, the average, the sum
and the quantity of the numbers. I have to use the scanf function in a
while loop. I tried to write the code, but i need help at some point
of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 1, number = 0, min = 0, max = 0, average = 0, sum = 0;

    while(i > 0) {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &i);
    }
    if (i <= 0) {
        i++;
        sum += i;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm stuck at the part where the "if" starts. What am i supposed to
write, to receive the minimum, maximum, sum, average and the quantity
of my typed numbers. And also, is the rest of my code right? Or am i
missing something?

Comment: If you start with `i == 0`, then will the loop ever run? I recommend that you learn about [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: You need to do each of these tasks as you read in the numbers.  As it stands now, the only information you have after the loop is the last number you entered.

Comment: There's A LOT missing in the while loop and the if statment is not necessary. You  should ask your teacher for help.

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not make sense. For example this loop

```
while(i > 0) {
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
}
```

calculates nothing.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int n = 0, min = 0, max = 0, sum = 0;

    int number;

    printf( "Enter a seria of numbers (0 or a negative number means exit)\n" );

    while ( scanf( "%d", &number ) == 1 && number > 0 )
    {
        ++n;
        sum += number;
        if ( min == 0 || number < min ) min = number;
        if ( max < number ) max = number;
    }

    printf( "The quantity of numbers: %d\n"
            "the minimum number: %d\n"
            "the maximum number: %d\n"
            "their sum : %d\n"
            "the average:  %d\n",
            n, min, max, sum, n == 0 ? 0 : sum / n );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like for example

```
Enter a seria of numbers (0 or a negative number means exit)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
The quantity of numbers: 9
the minimum number: 1
the maximum number: 9
their sum : 45
the average:  5
```